# Does Alpine Linux handle certs differently than Busybox?

Tags: docker, certificate, busybox, alpine-linux

I started with a base image errordeveloper/oracle-jdk.  This Dockerfile is shown here for reference:

```
FROM        progrium/busybox 
MAINTAINER  Ilya Dmitrichenko <errordeveloper@gmail.com>

RUN opkg-install curl ca-certificates

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/jdk1.8.0_31

RUN curl \
  --silent \
  --location \
  --retry 3 \
  --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/GeoTrust_Global_CA.crt \
  --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie;" \
  "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13/jdk-8u31-linux-x64.tar.gz" \
    | gunzip \
    | tar x -C /usr/ \
    && ln -s $JAVA_HOME /usr/java \
    && rm -rf $JAVA_HOME/src.zip $JAVA_HOME/javafx-src.zip $JAVA_HOME/man

ENV PATH ${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin

ENTRYPOINT [ "java" ]
CMD [ "-version" ]
```

I'd like to move this to Alpine Linux, so a made the following changes:

```
FROM        alpine
MAINTAINER  Ilya Dmitrichenko <errordeveloper@gmail.com>

RUN apk --update upgrade && apk add curl ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/jdk1.8.0_31

RUN curl \
  --silent \
  --location \
  --retry 3 \
  --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/GeoTrust_Global_CA.crt \
  --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie;" \
  "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13/jdk-8u31-linux-x64.tar.gz" \
    | gunzip \
    | tar x -C /usr/ \
    && ln -s $JAVA_HOME /usr/java \
    && rm -rf $JAVA_HOME/src.zip $JAVA_HOME/javafx-src.zip $JAVA_HOME/man

ENV PATH ${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin

ENTRYPOINT [ "java" ]
CMD [ "-version" ]
```

Mainly I changed the package management tool to pull down curl and ca-certificates.

After confirming the original builds clean on my machine (it does) I tried my version and got this error: (I turned off --silent on the curl to see it)

```
Step 4 : RUN curl   --location   --retry 3   --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/GeoTrust_Global_CA.crt   --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie;"   "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13/server-jre-8u31-linux-x64.tar.gz"     | gunzip     | tar x -C /usr/     && ln -s $JAVA_HOME /usr/java     && rm -rf $JAVA_HOME/man
 ---> Running in c91e4939f851
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/GeoTrust_Global_CA.crt
  CApath: none
gunzip: invalid magic
tar: short read
The command '/bin/sh -c curl   --location   --retry 3   --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/GeoTrust_Global_CA.crt   --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie;"   "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13/server-jre-8u31-linux-x64.tar.gz"     | gunzip     | tar x -C /usr/     && ln -s $JAVA_HOME /usr/java     && rm -rf $JAVA_HOME/man' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Does Alpine do something different here?  Why might my curl/certs be failing?

Comment: Rather old, but did you also try a PEM?

Answer (score 19):

Just to be sure the CA certificates are created/updated where they are supposed to, try and add (after [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/633853/141)) `update-ca-certificates`:

```
apk add ca-certificates
update-ca-certificates
```

In your case:

```
RUN apk --update upgrade && \
    apk add curl ca-certificates && \
    update-ca-certificates && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

Comment: That produced this error: WARNING: ca-certificates.crt does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping

Comment: Comparing Alpine and Busybox I also notice that Busybox has nss libs and Alpine doesn't.  Not sure if that was important so I added nss as another 'add'.  Unfortunately no dice on that either.

Comment: @Greg Are you using Alpine 3.2? (because this is supposed to be fixed in 3.2: https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/30)

Comment: Just tried with alpine:3.2, and it did remove that WARNING message.  It didn't, sadly, affect my original cert issue.